New lines from my mdx file are not rendering on my website, how can I fix this?
I'm using markdown files in my Next JS project, but when I view my files on local host there is no spaced between any lines or paragraphs. How can I fix this?
Markdown file:
 **Research**
    
    The first step involved deep research into our users and product to support our go-to-market strategy.
    
    Key focus areas included:
    
    - **User data:** Understanding where our product fits into users' lives and habits.


